# A problem about $\lim_{x\to 0}x^n(\ln x)^m.$

Tags: calculus, integration

Why $\lim_{x\to 0}x^n(\ln x)^m = 0?$ $n,m$ are  natural numbers.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please provide more context for this

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 2):

Oh!
I know how to solve it suddenly!
Just change it to $\lim_{x\to 0}x^{m+n}(\frac{lnx}{x})^m$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).